# How to easily use standard variants timing functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I am wondering if there is a way to quickly use more different timing functions across an app. For instance using [Robert Penner's](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/), many toolkits expose them and I am surprised Apple doesn't.

Basically a way to have a block based command as flexible as animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: in UIView.

I come up with this solution and it would be great to know if there are better alternatives.

```
//  UIView+CustomTimingFunction.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum {
    CustomTimingFunctionDefault,
    CustomTimingFunctionLinear,
    CustomTimingFunctionEaseIn,
    CustomTimingFunctionEaseOut,
    ....
} CustomTimingFunction;

@interface UIView (CustomTimingFunction)

- (void)animateProperty:(NSString *)property from:(id)from to:(id)to withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration customTimingFunction:(CustomTimingFunction)customTimingFunction competion:(void (^)(void))competion;

@end
```

and

```
//  UIView+CustomTimingFunction.m

#import "UIView+CustomTimingFunction.h"

@implementation UIView (CustomTimingFunction)

- (void)animateProperty:(NSString *)property from:(id)from to:(id)to withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration customTimingFunction:(CustomTimingFunction)customTimingFunction competion:(void (^)(void))competion
{
    [CATransaction begin]; {
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:competion];

        if([property isEqualToString:@"frame"]){
            CGRect fromRect = [from CGRectValue];
            CGPoint fromPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(fromRect), CGRectGetMidY(fromRect));
            CGRect toRect = [to CGRectValue];
            CGPoint toPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(toRect), CGRectGetMidY(toRect));

            CABasicAnimation *positionAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
            positionAnimation.timingFunction = [[self class] functionWithType:customTimingFunction];
            positionAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPosition];
            positionAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPosition];

            CABasicAnimation *boundsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
            boundsAnimation.timingFunction = [[self class] functionWithType:customTimingFunction];
            boundsAnimation.fromValue = from;
            boundsAnimation.toValue = to;

            CAAnimationGroup * group =[CAAnimationGroup animation];
            group.removedOnCompletion=NO;
            group.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
            group.animations = @[positionAnimation,boundsAnimation];
            group.duration = duration;

            [self.layer addAnimation:group forKey:property];
        }else{
            CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:property];
            animation.duration = duration;
            animation.timingFunction = [[self class] functionWithType:customTimingFunction];
            animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
            animation.fromValue = from;
            animation.toValue = to;
            [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
        }
    } [CATransaction commit];

}

+(CAMediaTimingFunction *)functionWithType:(CustomTimingFunction)type
{
    switch (type) {
        case CustomTimingFunctionDefault:
            return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
            break;
        case CustomTimingFunctionLinear:
            return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
            break;

        case CustomTimingFunctionEaseIn:
            return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
            break;
        case CustomTimingFunctionEaseOut:
            return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
            break;
        case CustomTimingFunctionEaseInOut:
            return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
            break;

        ....
    }

    NSLog(@"Couldn't find CustomTimingFunction, will return linear");
    return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: My answer was deleted for some unknown reason by @bill-the-lizard Bill the stupid Lizard. Check out https://github.com/robb/RBBAnimation/

Comment: Yeah, I checked it and I replied that I don't necessary need that much control over the animation. Would it be enough just to pass predefined/standard timing functions. The set Apple provides for animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: are way too limited. But definitely a very interesting library, thanks for sharing!